# Async collection loading for display in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wpf

In order to improve UX (User Experience) in WPF for huge collections, I would like to load collection items in asynchronnous and staggered fasion. While the WPF UI is virtualized by default, there very little support for *data* virtualization.
My goal in not to implement full data virtualization but rather to load *all* items incrementally, allowing read-only access to items loaded so far. Items are loaded over network from RESTful API, this however should remain implementaion detail. For this purpose I created a wrapper `CollectionLoader<T>`:

**CollectionLoader**

```
public interface IAsyncPageProvider<TItem>
{
    Task<Page<TItem>> GetPage(PageRequest pageRequest);
}

public class CollectionLoader<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const int defaultPageSize = 100;

    private bool _isLoading;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<T> Collection { get; }
    private IAsyncPageProvider<T> DataProvider { get; }
    // expose simplified state to UI
    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get { return _isLoading; }
        private set
        {
            _isLoading = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsLoading)));
        }
    }

    public CollectionLoader(ObservableCollection<T> collection, IAsyncPageProvider<T> dataProvider)
    {
        Collection = collection;
        DataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    public async Task Load(CancellationToken? token = null)
    {
        try
        {
            IsLoading = true; //notify UI state changed

            Collection.Clear(); // clean old items
            var pageSize = defaultPageSize;
            int currentItem = 0;
            Page<T> page;

            do
            {
                var request = new PageRequest() { 
                    Start = currentItem,
                    Length = pageSize
                };
                // query API
                page = await DataProvider.GetPage(request);
                // safe cancellation checkpoint
                token?.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                // add newly loaded items
                foreach (var item in page.Data)
                {
                    Collection.Add(item);
                }

                // advance current item (page start)
                currentItem += page.Data.Length;
                // increase page size to reduce round trips
                pageSize *= 2;
            }
            while (page.Data.Length > 0);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsLoading = false; //notify UI state changed
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
// sample ViewModel, starts loading procedure in ctor
public class TestVM : IDisposable
{
    CancellationTokenSource _source;
    CollectionLoader<string> Loader { get; }
    ICollectionView ItemsView { get; }
    ICommand CancelCommand { get; }

    public TestVM()
    {
        CancelCommand = new RelayCommand(() => _source?.Cancel(), () => Loader.IsLoading);
        var collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        // API mock with 100k list of strings and Task.Delay()
        Loader = new CollectionLoader<string>(collection, new PageProviderMock());
        ItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);
        // fire and forget
        _ = LoadItems();
    }

    // calling LoadItems should be safe regardless of state, 
    // could be called multiple times during VMs lifetime
    // only one loading procedure can run at a time for each instance
    private async Task LoadItems()
    {
        _source?.Cancel(); //cancel if running
        _source?.Dispose(); // dispose old token
        _source = new CancellationTokenSource(); // create new token
        await Loader.Load(_source.Token); // start async loading
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ((IDisposable)_source).Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Concerns** my main concern is about correctness of async in *both* implementation and sample usage, e.g. are tasks/tokens created, disposed and cancelled correctly? 
My secondary concern is corectness of separation of responsibilities, namely ownership of `ObservableCollection` / `ICollectionView` collection, there are conflicting requirements of VM ability to manipulate collection through user actions and Loaders responsibility to fully control (loading of) collection.

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer you were looking for but instead of using `CancellationToken?` you could try:

`Load(CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))`

The default is `CancellationToken.None`.

Comment: Good idea, I did not know that and if web source code is correct, it is what the .NET framework actually goes with.